# How do I install a new console font?

Tags: raspbian, terminal

I am making a console application running on Raspbian. I hit `CTRL+ALT+F2` to get to the console view, but now I do not have access to the same fonts I had in terminal. I am trying to install a specific ttf font. It works fine in terminal, but I need it to be full-screen. When I use `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`, I only get a list of a few fonts, not the one I am trying to install. I tried `setfont`, but I get a `Bad input file size` error, probably because I imagine true type fonts are not supported by the console. I tried converting the font using FontForge, but I'm not sure which format to convert it to, because the ones I tried gave the same error.

An answer to any of the following would fix my problem:

1. How do I use a ttf in the console?
2. How do I convert a ttf to a format the console could use?
3. How do I fullscreen the terminal (no GUIs or windows, just text)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console uses bitmapped (.psf) fonts, while X can use vector fonts such as TrueType (.ttf) in the terminal apps. There are a few console fonts you can select from with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` - terminus 16x32 being my favorite on a large display. There are a other bitmap console fonts around, but they tend to require manual installation and focus on smaller font sizes.

If you are running directly on the console, you can try the `fbterm` package. It will allow you to select from installed TrueType fonts. To install TrueType fonts:

1. Install fontconfig (`sudo apt install fontconfig`)
2. Copy .ttf fonts to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`
3. Rebuild font cache (`fc-cache -f -v`)

I was able to select a variety of fonts with no problems using something like `fbterm -s 32 -n "Liberation Mono"` (-s to specify size, -n to specify font name as shown in `fc-list`).

Comment: I am required to use a more retro-style font like Joystix Monospace, but I can only find that in ttf. Is there any way to convert that?

Comment: From what I've been able to find, converting .ttf to .psf is difficult and generally not worth it. You might want to look into `fbterm`. I haven't used it, but it is supposed to support truetype and other features using the framebuffer, no X required.