# Console Font Recommendation

Tags: pi-4, terminal, raspbian-lite

Can anyone help me find a console font that is wider that it is tall?

When I change the console font, there are some choices like VGA, Terminus, etc. All of these fonts have choices like 8x8, 8x12, etc. What I need is an alternative font that is approximately 12x8. If there aren't any premade fonts like this, perhaps there is a way to force a font width x height manually?

Reason for this is that I'm using a super-resolution (2560x240) on a CRT monitor. This is a technique used to minimize scaling artifacts when dialing in pixel perfect emulation for arcade games. Unfortunatly, the console font can't really scale well with such an extreme aspect ratio, it kind of squishes up. I tried some of the frame buffer resolutions and they were more legible, but they are HUGE (16x*), so not so useful. Perhaps a smaller frame-buffer font would do the trick as well?

Thanks

using raspian lite, RPI4

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || Your question isn't clear enough, add more details.

Comment: Okay, I changed the post to have some more detail. I can add more specifics if you think I am missing something. That's all I could think of...

Answer (score 1):

This answer recently got a downvote, so I've tried to make it clearer.

If your Raspberry Pi **forces** a screen resolution, **the screen will stretch it** to fit.
You can use that trick to make the console font taller, *without having to go build a custom font*.

For example, if your screen is 1280x1024, use `raspi-config` to set the resolution to 1280x720. After a reboot, the monitor will see the changed resolution, and will stretch it vertically to fit.

IMHO, it's a much more straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you have a suitable font already or are artistic enough, you could create your own font of the required dimensions and then use [PSF Tools](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/) (and `gzip`) to convert it into the correct file format for use on the console.

I think you could also hand-craft a font using the [BDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph_Bitmap_Distribution_Format) format (with a bit of patience and some graph paper?) but I'm not so sure that you can use the resulting file directly on the Raspberry Pi and *PSF Tools* does not seem to accept it as an input.

See also [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71913/93934) answer that might be of use.